# Equation for an ellipsoid pointing towards a point

Tags: geometry, python

Sorry beforehand if this question is too basic!

I would like to build an utility to create an ellipsoid pointing to a certain point in 3D space.

The equation I am using to built it:
$$
 x = a \, \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) \\
 y = b \, \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) \\
 z = c \, \cos(\theta)
$$

The center point is $C=(0,0,0)$ and for $a= 10$, $b=1$ and $c=1$ yields https://ibb.co/kmjHp6V

I would like to build the ellipsoid pointing toward a point in space.
So if the user supplied $p = (1,1,1)$ the geometry would still maintain $C=(0,0,0)$ but point towards that direction.

What are the changes to the Eq. above to account for this?

I am using python to build the geometry.
The code is listed bellow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)   
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100) 

x = 10*np.outer( np.sin(theta), np.cos(phi) )
y = 1*np.outer( np.sin(theta), np.sin(phi) )
z = 1*np.outer( np.cos(theta), np.ones_like(phi) )

ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, alpha=0.5)
ax.set_xlim3d(-10, 10)
ax.set_ylim3d(-10, 10)
ax.set_zlim3d(-10, 10)
```

Comment: What does it mean for an ellipse/ellipsoid to point toward a point?

Comment: I can give you an example in 2D.  https://ibb.co/4dYpqBR.

In that image I set a point. It uses the atan2 function to get the angle and draws and ellipse form the calculated angle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153768/draw-ellipse-and-ellipsoid-in-matlab [code in matlab]. I would like to be able to do the same for a 3D geometry [ellipsoid].

Comment: So the major axis has to pass through the given point?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use rotation matrices, but in 3D there will be infinitely many possible solutions unless it happens that $b=c$.

Comment: The major axis does not to pass through the point, just point towards it. For my case b = c = 1 , only a is different

Answer (score 1):

Your code has to determine the longest axis of the ellipsoid, and use that as the $z'$ axis of a local $O'x'y'z'$ frame attached to the ellipsoid, that its origin $O'$ at the point $C$ which is supplied.  In addition, you have a point $p$ that is also supplied by the user, from which you compute the direction of the $z'$ axis as follows

$u_3 = \dfrac{ p - C }{\| p - C \| } $

Then your code has to compute two mutually orthogonal unit vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ that are orthogonal to the vector $u_3$ calculated above.  There is an infinite number of ways to select the set $\{u_1, u_2 \}$.  Now a rotation matrix representing the frame $O'x'y'z'$ rigidly attached to the ellipsoid is given by

$R = [u_1, u_2, u_3] $

$R$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix whose columns are the three unit vectors $u_1, u_2, u_3 $.  Assuming the semi-axes lengths are $a,b,c$ with $ a \le b \lt c $, then in the frame $O'x'y'z'$ we have

$ x' = a \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) \\
 y' = b \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) \\
z' = c \cos(\theta) $

If $r'=[x',y',z']^T$ is the coordinate vector of a point on the ellipsoid in the local $O'x'y'z'$ frame, and $r=[x,y,z]^T $ is the corresponding coordinate vector in the world frame then

$ r = C + R r' $

And this will specify the ellipsoid in terms of the parameters $\theta \in [0, \pi] $ and $\phi \in [0, 2 \pi]$.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. A bit of clarification so that I can implement this. The orthogonal vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$.  $u_1$  I can find through the dot product by fixing e.g., $x=1$ and $z=1$. $u_2$ I can get through the cross product of $u_1$ and $u_3$. Afterwards, normalize every calculated vector.  What I am not getting is the following part. $x', y' z'$ are built with $a,b,x$ [same as the original] and later I just have to multiply the rotation matrix $R$ with my original $x',y',z'$?

Comment: Yes.  For example if $u_3 = [2, -2, 3]^T / \sqrt{17} $ then you can take $u_1 = [3, 0, -2]^T/\sqrt{13}$ , and $u_2 = u_3 \times u_1 $.  From this you have $R=[u_1, u_2,  u_3]$, and if $ a= 5, b = 2, c = 3 $ then re-order them, so that you have $a' = 2 , b'= 3, c' = 5$ and use the spherical coordinates together with $a',b',c'$ as in the solution but with $a,b,c$ replaced with $a',b',c'$.

Comment: This is not a unique solution.  To obtain all possible solutions, calculate $u_1, u_2$ as above, and define the rotated axes as follows $ u'_1 = \cos(\beta) u_1 + \sin(\beta) u_2 $ and $u'_2 = - \sin(\beta) u_1 + \cos(\beta) u_2 $, then your rotation matrix would become $R = [u'_1, u'_2, u_3 ] $ .  By changing $\beta$ you generate all possible orientations of the desired ellipsoid.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Another clarification if possible. How did you pass from $a=5, b=2,c =3$ to $a' = 2, b'=3, c' = 5$? Additionally, the rotation along the ellipsoidal axis is not important for me.

Comment: I ordered the given lengths $\{5, 2, 3\}$ to the sorted list $\{ 2, 3, 5 \}$ , then $a,b,c$ are thus redefined as $a = 2, b = 3, c = 5 $, so that we can use these values in calculating $x',y',z'$ in the solution.

Comment: I will make a new answer with the code and output I am getting